# Where did the name "The Borg" -- as in Star Trek -- come from?

Tags: star-trek, names

How did the creators of Star Trek's biggest bad guy -- the Borg Collective -- come up with its name?

Comment: Sounds Swedish...

Comment: It seems very likely there is actually an answer to this question and the dup-linked to doesn't have it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always thought that since the Borg are part organic and part machine that means they are cyborgs. So the creators must have just shortened the word to Borg.
Again, that's just my interpretation.
However, I did find this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_%28Star_Trek%29) that alludes to my interpretation; In the novel Lost Souls, it details how the Borg were created (one version anyway.)

Comment: The word cyborg, in turn, [is a shortened form of](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cyborg) cybernetic organism.